# How to get the next primary key value as the Insert command is issued by ExecuteStoreCommand?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-6.1

I am using EF6.1 with MVC3 and ASP.NET 4.5 with SQL Server 2008 SP2 (Dev) and Azure SQL (Test, Live)

I am trying to speed up DML performance and I am finding the AddObject Method in EF slow. Not sure is tracking is the cause, and I should somehow alter this, but for the moment I am resorting a more direct approach by using :

```
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT INTO Order ([SupplierId]) Values ({0})", SupplierId);
```

However, how do I get the newly generated PK value after the commit to the Database. In the DB, it is an integer Identity column. Can any of these direct DB methods return a new PK value, like "AddObject" does after "SaveChanges()". Also I am very mindful of the issue of getting the wrong record if another user inserts into the same table at the same time.

The only other workaround which would work is to store a Guid with the Insert and then do:

```
var myOrder = db.Order.First(r=>r.Guid==myGuid);
int myId = myOrder.Id;
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

When I use this ExecuteStoreCommand/Select by Guid approach on SQL Azure, I reduce the Insert Transaction time from 300ms to 60ms, so it is significant.

Incidentally on my local dev server which has SQL Server on the same machine the unimproved code took 90 ms instead of 300ms. So it seems the network latency in Azure is penalising the "AddObject" approach more harshly.

Comment: After you insert, you can get PK using scope_identity() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: @deusExCore , Thanks for this, however is this true when working within the application ie Will a command following ExecuteStoreCommand still be in the same scope, and therefore guaranteed to pick up the correct New Id, and not another user's Id from another concurrent insert?

Comment: Sql locks table when doing work on it. So, it will be correct id you are picking with scope_identity

Comment: Thanks again for this, but would the completion of ExecuteStoreCommand not release any lock once it finished, and before any future command, unless it was part of a bigger transaction block which contained both commands?

Comment: Can you put some sample code together as an answer. I think your may be right, as the "Context" object retains the connection, and as long as you reuse the same context object then one should be protected from other user activity.

Comment: Thanks I have now got this working, in tandem with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153878/struggling-with-efs-execute-commands-to-get-the-newest-id-after-an-insert. So if you want to create an answer then I will mark it up. Thanks.