# Struggling with EF's Execute Commands to get the newest ID after an insert

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

I am issuing an Insert statement directly against the DB (SQL Server 2008), using EF6.1 on ASP.NET 4.5. I need to get the newest ID in the transaction post insert, however I cannot quite figure out the code.

This is what I have at present:

```
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT INTO Order ([SupplierId]) Values ({0})", SID);
Int32 intId = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Int32>("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()").First();
var myOrder = db.Order.First(r => r.Id == intId);
```

The above example is simplified. Is it possible combine the commands ie something like, or what?

```
Int32 intId = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Int32>("INSERT INTO Order ([SupplierId]) Values ({0}); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()",SID).First();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicions were correct. This works:

```
Int32 intId = (Int32)db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Decimal>("INSERT INTO Order ([SupplierId]) Values ({0}); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", SID).First();
```

Hope this helps someone.

EDIT: As per Gert's answer, I have changed this from @@IDENTITY to use SCOPE_IDENTITY, more info also at [More Information about Scope_Identity](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: You should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` though.